# GNURadio non supported platform

Tags: fpga, gnuradio

I am just new on GNURadio and for a project I need to use GNURadio with an FPGA platform different from the ones already supported in the GNURadio project...
Is it feasible to develop design for different platforms?? I must a different FPGA since my board include DA/AD converters with higher BW than the supported platforms.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This question makes no sense. GNU Radio is a software project running on CPUs. We don not support *any* FPGA platforms. Maybe you're mixing something up. Unless you specify to which things you're actually referring, I'm sad, but I'll have to close this question as uncler.

Answer (score 2):

GNURadio is a framework for processing data on a CPU. They added some RFNOC stuff that is supposed to do your processing on Ettus USRP FPGAs, but I'm not sure how well that works. GNURadio does not limit itself to any specific hardware front end, however you will have to write the custom drivers yourself. GNURadio uses UHD as the driver to work with Ettus USRPs, and there are other drivers (such as rtl-sdr) already integrated into GNURadio that work with hardware front-ends other than Ettus USRPs.

So to answer your question, yes you can use GNURadio with other FPGA platforms, but you will need to build the drivers yourself. Is it feasible to develop designs for different platforms? Yes, but there will be a significant amount of work that goes into it, which depends on your specific application and time frame for if it's worth it. You have not given any specifics so it's impossible for me to estimate.